# I am getting HTTP 400 error in apache server

Tags: apache, http, http-status-code-400

I am getting HTTP 400 error in our application.The error is coming frequently but some times we are able to access application without 400.
There is one SSO application in which our application's link is added so same session details we are getting in our application.But when i login to the other application from same domain, and refresh the first one, I get HTTP 400 error. other applications cookies are also getting in our application.

I am using apache 2.2 on web server and tomcat 7 on app server. 
I have tried increasing LimitRequestFieldSize on web server but it didn't work and current LimitRequestFieldSize is 65535.
Technology stack :- backend :- Java,Documentum 
apache 2.2  web server tomcat 7 on app server

Kindly check and provide solution it will be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the error log say? Typically, a 400 response is due to unexpected request body data and will be coming from whatever application or service is handling that request

Comment: We are getting difference in cookies for working and non-working condition(HTTP 400).If I am deleting some cookies then it works fine.